# XPath to select and concatenate all text nodes

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I'm scraping data from a website which looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <blockquote>
    <div>
      Do not select this.
    </div>
    How do I select only this…
    <br />
    and this…
    <br />
    and this in a single node?
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Suppose a snippet like this appears 20 times on a single page and I want to get all of the text within the `<blockquote>` but ignore everything within child nodes such as the inner `div`.

I therefore use:

```
html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@class='content']/blockquote/text()[normalize-space()]")
```

However, this separates `How do I select only this…`, `and this…`, `and this in a single node?` into individual elements within the `xml_nodeset` structure.

What should I do to essentially concatenate all these text nodes into one and return the same 20 elements (or a single one in case all I had was just this example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the nodes you with CSS or XPATH with `xml_remove()` function.

```
library(rvest)

text <- '<div class="content">
  <blockquote>
    <div>
      Do not select this.
    </div>
    How do I select only this…
    <br />
    and this…
    <br />
    and this in a single node?
  </blockquote>
</div>'

myhtml <- read_html(text)

#select the nodes you don't want to select
do_not_select <- myhtml %>%
    html_nodes("blockquote>div") #using css

#remove those nodes
xml_remove(do_not_select)
```

You can remove the white space and \n later

```
#sample result
myhtml %>%
    html_text()
[1] "\n  \n    \n    How do I select only this…\n    \n    and this…\n    \n    and this in a single node?\n  \n"
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much! I'd like to see if this can be done with just XPath in `rvest` but I'm most likely going to accept your answer since XPath 2.0 does not seem to be supported.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with XPATH syntax, but it will work the same as long as you select the nodes correctly. And using `xml_remove()` will remove all selected nodes.

Answer (score 5):

You can try below XPath to concatenate all child substrings:

```
"string-join(//*[@class='content']/blockquote/text()[normalize-space()], ' ')"
```

The output is

```
How do I select only this… and this… and this in a single node?
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't doubt you're technically correct but unfortunately `rvest` does not seem to support XPath 2.0 because it says: `xmlXPathCompOpEval: function string-join not found`. I was also trying to do this with `concat()` but to no avail.

Comment: In case you know for sure how much text nodes you need, you can use `concat(//*[@class='content']/blockquote/text()[normalize-space()][1], ' ', //*[@class='content']/blockquote/text()[normalize-space()][2], ' ', //*[@class='content']/blockquote/text()[normalize-space()][3])`, but it's not a good option...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't, and like you said, it doesn't seem like a good option indeed. I'm going to find out more about the state of XPath 2.0 in `rvest` or whatever library is being used underneath, and perhaps ask the developers if they plan to implement this.