# Find string in text of script element

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-playwright

I'm trying to scrape a page where I want to wait until a string has been detected in a `script` element before returning the page's HTML.

Here's my MRE scraper:

```
from scrapy import Request, Spider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod


class FlashscoreSpider(Spider):
    name = "flashscore"
    custom_settings = {
        "DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS": {
            "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
            "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
        },
        "TWISTED_REACTOR": "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor",
        "REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION": "2.7",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url="https://www.flashscore.com/match/WKM03Vff/#/match-summary/match-summary",
            meta=dict(
                dont_redirect=True,
                playwright=True,
                playwright_page_methods=[
                    PageMethod(
                        method="wait_for_selector",
                        selector="//script[contains(text(), 'WKM03Vff')]",
                        timeout=5000,
                    ),
                ],
            ),
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        print("I've loaded the page ready to parse!!!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(FlashscoreSpider)
    process.start()
```

This results in the following error:

```
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 5000ms exceeded.
```

My understanding is that this is because there are multiple text nodes in `script` and I'm only picking up the first one with the XPath. As the string I'm looking for is in a later node then I get the `TimeoutError` error.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50822483/11277108) gives a neat solution however scrapy doesn't support XPath 2.0 so when I use:

```
"string-join(//script/text()[normalize-space()], ' ')"
```

I get the following error:

```
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Unexpected token "string-join(" while parsing selector "string-join(//script/text()[normalize-space()], ' ')"
```

There is an alternative given in the comments to the answer but my worry there is a changing number of text nodes.

From some fairly intensive googling I don't think there is a robust XPath solution. However, is there a CSS equivalent? I've tried:

```
"script:has-text('WKM03Vff')"
```

However, that results in a `Timeout` exception again.

Comment: That page has 35 script elements and finishes loading after 7.5 seconds (7500 ms) so increasing the timeout to 10000 could be a good test.

Comment: Thanks - me being dopey and not spotting the additional `script` elements. Think the question still holds though. Tried boosting to 20000 and still get the `Timeout` error :(

Comment: I just checked it against a fiber-connection (so rather fast) and the provided XPath (woks just fine) should give a result in 1 second.
I suppose something else is wrong

Comment: Did you check the whole code or just the XPath on the page? The latter works fine but my example above definitely doesn't!

Comment: you shouldn't need to wait at all for the contents of script tags since they typically already exist within the html and don't need to be rendered.  In fact your xpath selector works just fine when using the standard scrapy shell without using playwright

Comment: @Alexander... it does indeed but I get detected as a robot using just scrapy, hence playwright

Comment: you seemed to have missed my point though, you shouldn't need to wait for script tags, you should be able to immediately access them from within the parse method.

Comment: Ok I'm with you now! Thanks for persevering!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, script tags typically do not require waiting for any amount of time because they do not require being rendered.

You should simply be able to immdiately access their contents from within the parse method.

For example:

```
from scrapy import Request, Spider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod


class FlashscoreSpider(Spider):
    name = "flashscore"
    custom_settings = {
        "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": False,
        "DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS": {
            "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
            "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
        },
        "TWISTED_REACTOR": "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor",
        "REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION": "2.7",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url="https://www.flashscore.com/match/WKM03Vff/#/match-summary/match-summary",
            meta=dict(
                dont_redirect=True,
                playwright=True,
                playwright_include_page=True),
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.xpath("//script[contains(text(), 'WKM03Vff')]"))
        print(response.xpath("//script[contains(text(), 'WKM03Vff')]/text()").get())
        print("I've loaded the page ready to parse!!!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(FlashscoreSpider)
    process.start()
```

#### partial output

```
2023-09-13 00:07:02 [scrapy-playwright] DEBUG: [Context=default] Request: <GET 
https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/202210.1.0/assets/otCommonStyles.css> 
(resource type: fetch, referrer: https://www.flashscore.com/)
[<Selector query="//script[contains(text(), 'WKM03Vff')]" 
data='<script>\n\t\t\twindow.environment = {"ev...'>]

                        window.environment = {"event_id_c":"WKM03Vff",
"eventStageTranslations":{"1":"&nbsp;","45":"To finish","42":"Awaiting 
updates","2":"Live","17": "Set 1","18":"Set 2","19":"Set 3","20":"Set 
4","21":"Set 5","47":"Set 1 - Tiebreak","48":"Set 2 - Tiebreak","49":"Set 3 - 
Tiebreak","50":"Set 4 - Tiebreak","51":"Set 5 - Tiebreak","46":"Break 
Time","3":"Finished",....p10:100","port":443,"sslEnabled":true,"namespace":"\/f
s\/fs3_","projectId":2,"enabled":false},"project_id":2};

I've loaded the page ready to parse!!!
2023-09-13 00:07:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```